# Maxima: Translation operator on functions

Tags: function, maxima

I would like to define a translation operator L that from a function q outputs q(x-1) for all x i.e. the same function but shifted by one to the left. I defined it this way:

```
(%i0) L(q) := q(x-1);
```

However, if I apply the operator twice

```
(%i1) L(L(q));
```

it outputs

```
(%o1) q(x-1)(x-1)
```

instead of

```
(%o1) q(x-2)
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L` has to return a function for this kind of nesting to work.

Perhaps, a simple substitution is enough for the task:

```
L(f) := subst(x=x-1,f)$
L(sin(x));     L(L(sin(x)));
  sin(x - 1)
  sin(x - 2)
```

A macro with lambda would also work:

```
L(q) ::= buildq([q], lambda([x], q(x-1)));
```

So, when, for example, `f(x):= x + 1, g(x) := sin(%pi*(x-1)/4)`:

```
f(1);    L(f)(1);    L(L(f))(1);
2
1
0
g(1);    L(g)(1);    L(L(g))(1);
0
-1/sqrt(2)
-1
```

Comment: It's a step forward, but in my case it is important that symbolic expressions get simplified also, not just the numerics i.e. L(L(q)) must yield q(x+2)…

Comment: @GLorieul, then why not just simply `L(f) := subst(x=x-1,f)`?  `L(L(sin(x))) = sin(x-2)`

Comment: sorry seems I missed the second part of your answer… That's exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks! (Perhaps you might want to edit your answer and only keep the second part?)

Comment: @GLorieul, I added the second part after your comment. :) I'll edit my answer again but I'm inclined to leave the other part as it works differently.